# Deleting elements from a list of dictionaries with certain key value

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a bunch of geographical locations saved as a list of dictionaries. One of the keys is country ID, I want to remove all the the locations with different country ID than 112. I wrote this piece of code. For some reason it removes the majority of non-112 entries, but doesn't remove all of them. Here is the loop i wrote for this filtering:

```
counter = 0
i=0
while counter < len(CS_list):
    country = CS_list[i]["AddressInfo"].get("CountryID")
    if country != 112:
        CS_list.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1
    counter += 1
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVEQk.jpg) is the list after running this loop. As you can see, still there are some non-112 left, even though a lot of such entries have been removed. It really baffles me. Any idea why it's like this?

Edit:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBbjp.jpg) is an example of element of the input list. After running the loop I want to have the same list but without all the elements with country ID different than 112.

Comment: Post the list in the question description and expected output. If the list is too long, just put a sample input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would just build a new list containing only the elements you want.

```
countries = [
    {'AddressInfo': {'CountryID': 112}},
    {'AddressInfo': {'CountryID': 8}},
    {'AddressInfo': {'CountryID': 2}},
    {'AddressInfo': {'CountryID': 4}},
    {'AddressInfo': {'CountryID': 112}},
]
countries = [
    country for country in countries
    if country.get('AddressInfo', {}).get('CountryID') == 112
]  
print(countries)
```

If you explicitly want to remove those entries from the existing list, you can assign the result of the list comprehension to the original list as a slice:

```
countries[:] = [
    country for country in countries
    if country.get('AddressInfo', {}).get('CountryID') == 112
]
```

Comment: Thank you, seems it's working now! Still don't understand why it didn't work before though.